# REST API many-to-many relationships

Tags: rest, api

For example, we have an application with such resources: **Person**, **Movie**, **Cartoon**, **TV Show**.

Stars, directors, ... is **Person**s. Each person can have some role in Movie, Cartoon or TV-Show.

Is there best practices for implementing such relationships in REST API?

Is it good to have many endpoints for Persons?

```
/movies/{id}/persons
/cartoons/{id}/persons
/persons/{id}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might not want to have 
/movies or /cartoons 
You can have something like /motion-pictures (maybe not the right name but you get the idea) and as an attribute for the resource have type of movie or animation  and then:

/motion-pictures/{id}/actors

Where each actor has a role as attributes.
Also in your db you can have the many to many relationship but show that relationship from actor to motion-pictures as hateaos in actor representation.

Something like hateaos links to movies they played in:

```
/motion-pictures/123
/motion-pictures/567
```